# VB.NET Database reading error

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have this SQL sentence for retrieving a specific role (by the column RoleID) from the table Roles:

```
DBBroker.getInstance.read("SELECT * FROM Roles WHERE RoleID='" & role.roleID & "';")
```

The thing is that when my program runs the sentence, I obtain this error:

[image: Error obtained]

I work with a Microsoft Access Database in which RoleID is defined as Autonumber while in my program it is defined as String. Anyway I tried changing Types but it still fails.

I have too much code in the program so I cannot include it here, but I'm open for any requests regarding a specific part of the program.

Thanks

By the way I worked before on another similar database and the exact same clause did work indeed.

Comment: Are you sure the quotes around RoleID= are correct?

Comment: If RoleID is a number on the database then do not use quotes around it. But you really should learn how to use parameters to avoid this problem and sql injection paths.

Comment: @steve it worked!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Though you solved your problem,i am answering this just to describe and help guys who visit this page in future**

Here's a one line explanation of the issue :

**The data type you set for the column in the table of the database is different than the type of value you are passing**

For example : In simple words, you have a word and a number , can you add them ? I mean in a mathematical way ? The answer is **NO**.

Now assuming that your data-type for the `RoleID` column is `Integer` but `role.RoleId` is of type/returns value of type `String` , then there will be a data-type mismatch as one is an `integer` and the other is a `String`.

Now, going through the comments , i see that you've solved your issue.Now, let me explain how you solved it.

Your sql query looks like this :

```
 "SELECT * FROM Roles WHERE RoleID='" & role.roleID & "';"
```

Let's point out the main relevant part :

```
 RoleID='" & role.roleID & "'
```

Here,before you close the string `RoleID=` with double quotes, you use `'`(single quote).In sql-queries, single quotes are used to declare/give a value(of type **STRING**) to the required/given parameter(of the query).

In order to pass an `Integer` value ,you can pass it without the `'` single quote like this :

```
 RoleID=12345
```

So, the answer is simple:You were passing some data of type **String** to a column which expects data/even if the passed value is of type `intger` but because you were using `'` single quotes when passing the values,the quote had converted it to a `String` ..So, all u have to do(had to do-in your case) is remove the two single quotes(`'`)

Hope this helps to enrich your knowledge :)